# Need help on nav SQL for customers with no sales in current year

Tags: sql

I want to pull out customers that are not blocked, but have no sales in this year. But they may have sales in previous years this is the bit I'm stuck with.

```
select 'company ' AS COMPANY,c.[No_], c.[Name], SA.[Year No_]
from [company$customer] c
left join 
[company$Sales Analysis]sa on sa.[Customer No_] = c.[No_]
where sa.[Year No_] IS NULL 
AND c.[blocked] ='0'
```

Comment: Can you give us a data example we can work on (1 or 2 rows) ?

Comment: Company  No  Name  year 
company 4000 h1 null
company 3212 h5 null
company 6000 h4 null
company 4890 h3 null     this brings me out all customers with no sales ... I'm still missing the customers which have sales up to  bu not including this year

Comment: Edit your question ;)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could include a [Year No_] constraint in the join condition.

From the comments, my understanding is that the "current year" indication is 2017 in your data.  You want the join condition to include **only** sales in the current year, so that the outer join will generate a NULL [Year No_] value for anyone who doesn't have a sale marked 2017 (whether or not they have older sales).  Then the NULL check in your WHERE clause picks up on those generated NULL values.

Something like

```
select 'company ' AS COMPANY,c.[No_], c.[Name], SA.[Year No_]
  from           [company$customer] c
       left join [company$Sales Analysis]sa 
              on sa.[Customer No_] = c.[No_]
             and sa.[Year No_] = 2017
 where sa.[Year No_] IS NULL 
   AND c.[blocked] ='0'
```

Of course you may want to use a parameter or a system date-based expression instead of hard-coding 2017, but the basic idea is there...

Comment: yes have tried this but I'm finding it still shows me customers from this year as they may also have had previous sales in the previous year as well

Comment: The query I show above would exclude those; I think you've tried something similar but didn't read the query I posted.

Comment: Or alternately there's something you haven't explained about your data, in which case more detail will be needed for anyone to give a "correct" answer.

Comment: Thanks Mark  , I have just tried it again  , and while it displays the Year no as Null  , It still shows me customers with sales in the current year 2017... even when I try <  than I still get the same types of results

Comment: Your use of the phrase "the current year 2017" confirms that you aren't giving us enough information.  Tell me enough that I can understand what makes 2017 "the current year" and I'll provide an edit that should work.

Comment: The sales table has a field with year no on it ... each sales is entered on it with the year no .... the current year has sales entered as 2017  , against the customer no .... i am looking for all sales up to and including 2016 but are not in 2017 ... hope this makes a little more sense

Comment: Ok, try the new version above.

Comment: Super !  , it works bringing back the data I want  , thank you for all your help , Mark